# E2010 Incompatible Types, why?

Tags: delphi, unicode, types

I'm getting this error:

```
[DCC Error] JwaStrSafe.pas(2277): E2010 Incompatible types: 'PSTRSAFE_LPWSTR' and 'PSTRSAFE_LPTSTR'
```

The following is the relevant portion of code from JwaStrSafe.pas (from Jedi Api), I'm compiling with the symbol UNICODE defined:

```
type

STRSAFE_LPWSTR = PWIDECHAR;
PSTRSAFE_LPWSTR = ^STRSAFE_LPWSTR;

{$IFDEF UNICODE}
  STRSAFE_LPTSTR = STRSAFE_LPWSTR;
  PSTRSAFE_LPTSTR = ^STRSAFE_LPTSTR;
{$ELSE}
  ...
{$ENDIF}

...
//function declaration
function StringCchCopyExW(
  {__out_ecount(cchDest)}pszDest : STRSAFE_LPWSTR;
  {__in}cchDest : size_t;
  {__in}const pszSrc : STRSAFE_LPCWSTR;
  {__deref_opt_out_ecount(pcchRemaining^)}ppszDestEnd : PSTRSAFE_LPWSTR;
  {__out_opt}pcchRemaining : PSize_t;
  {__in}dwFlags : Cardinal) : HRESULT; stdcall; forward; external;

...
//var passed to function
ppszDestEnd : PSTRSAFE_LPTSTR;

...

{$IFDEF UNICODE}
  result := StringCchCopyExW(pszDest, cchDest, pszSrc, ppszDestEnd, pcchRemaining, dwFlags);
{$ELSE}
  result := StringCchCopyExA(pszDest, cchDest, pszSrc, ppszDestEnd, pcchRemaining, dwFlags);
{$ENDIF}
```

I get the error on the call of StringCchCopyExW, on parameter ppszDestEnd.

Looking at the type definition I understand that PSTRSAFE_LPTSTR is a pointer type to STRSAFE_LPTSTR which is just an alias of STRSAFE_LPWSTR, why are PSTRSAFE_LPTSTR and PSTRSAFE_LPWSTR incompatible?

**Solution**
Thanks to David's explanation I replaced

```
PSTRSAFE_LPTSTR = ^STRSAFE_LPTSTR;
```

with

```
PSTRSAFE_LPTSTR = PSTRSAFE_LPWSTR;
```

now the code compiles without errors.

Thanks

Comment: What version of Delphi are you using?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can reproduce this easily enough in XE2, and I imagine it will behave the same in all other versions. To make it simpler I've cut it down to this:

```
program PointerTypeCompatibility;
{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}
type
  A = Integer;
  B = Integer;
var
  ptA: ^A;
  ptB: ^B;
begin
  ptA := ptB;
end.
```

This also produces E2010. However, if you enable the [type-checked pointers](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Type-checked_pointers_%28Delphi%29) option, then the code compiles successfully. In fact the documentation of that compiler options states:

> In the {$T-} state, distinct pointer types other than Pointer are incompatible (even if they are pointers to the same type). In the {$T+} state, pointers to the same type are compatible.

---

Thanks to Ken White for pointing me at the useful help topic [Type Compatibility and Identity](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Type_Compatibility_and_Identity). The pertinent extracts are that types T1 and T2 are *assignment compatible* if:

> T1 and T2 are compatible pointer types.

The documentation also states that types are *type compatibile* if:

> Both types are (typed) pointers to the same type and the {$T+} compiler directive is in effect.

So this documents the observed behaviour and leads me to this example:

```
program PointerTypeCompatibilityTake2;
{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}
{$TYPEDADDRESS OFF}
var
  P1,P2: ^Integer;
  P3: ^Integer;
begin
  P1 := P2;//compiles
  P1 := P3;//E2008 Incompatible types
end.
```

So, to summarise:

- When type-checked pointers is disabled, pointers are assignment compatible if the pointers are of the same type.
- When type-checked pointers is enabled, pointers are assignment compatible if the pointers point to the the same type.

I have to confess to being ignorant of the history and reasoning behind the type-checked pointer setting, so I can't offer any explanation for why the compiler is the way it is.

Comment: This might help: [Type Identity](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Type_Compatibility_and_Identity).

Comment: You're welcome. You'd already put so much work into it without the link; I didn't want to use it and steal your work. :) Nice job - +1.

Comment: @Ken Thanks. I'd have been very pleased for you to have added an answer that added value ;-)

Comment: Quote from [$TYPEDADDRESS](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Type-checked_pointers_%28Delphi%29) help page: _In the {$T-} state, distinct pointer types other than Pointer are incompatible (even if they are pointers to the same type)_

Comment: In XE5 this (put {$TYPEDADDRESS OFF} after {$R *.DFM})  solved the syntax error while using BASS dll and doing a BASS_ChannelSetSync